# Twitter atom don't retrieving old tweets

Tags: php, xml, twitter

I have an application that consumes a twitter xml (obtained in http://search.twitter.com/) and shows the last 5 tweets posted by an account. But now it's only retrieving tweets posted in last 7 days.

The request made by me is something like:

> http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:twitter&rpp=5&show_user=true

Anyone that passed for the same problem can give me an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: When parsing I would use json format, because I think it is easier to parse using json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

`rpp=5` means "do not return more than 5 tweets". Your query returns the 5 least recent tweets of the user no matter how old they are.

The only way to restrict the age of the tweets in the result is the parameter [since_id](http://search.twitter.com/api/).

**Edit:** The search API seems to be [limited to 7 days](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/235d7ed0a30878e9/2ff55a8bccf77b88).

Comment: It should be working as you said, but it's returning last 5 tweets IF them is newer than 7 days. If you replace rpp to rpp=30, you'll se that it's not bringing the last 30 tweets of @twitter.

Comment: @pedrorezende: In fact. According to http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search the 7-days-limit should only apply with certain operators. But I found http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/235d7ed0a30878e9/2ff55a8bccf77b88 ...